# How to set window pane size in the class ApplicationAdapter

Tags: java, libgdx, size

I recently started working with java and I am currently working on a school project.

I want to set the size of the window that opens up when I run my code.

A friend set up my project and I'm working with libGdx, it extends the class ApplicationAdapter:

`public class Mainclass extends ApplicationAdapter {`

What must I do to set the size of the window pane that opens up?

(I'm working with eclipse, if that changes anything)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you should really start by reading some tutorials:

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki

http://www.gamefromscratch.com/page/LibGDX-Tutorial-series.aspx

To answer your question, the windows size is a *configuration* setting:

```
LwjglApplicationConfiguration config = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
config.width = 800;
config.height = 600;
new LwjglApplication(new MyAppListener(), config);
```

This comes from here:

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Querying-%26-configuring-graphics-%28monitors%2C-display-modes%2C-vsync%29